# Return variable without global variables? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to keep this closed up in a function. It works if I make color a global variable, but doesn't work otherwise. Is there a way I can make this work without a global variable?

```
import tkinter

def pick_color():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    color = "blue"
    def blue():
        color = "blue"
        root.destroy()
    def red():
        color = "red"
        root.destroy()
    b = tkinter.Button(root, text="blue", command = blue)
    b.pack()
    c = tkinter.Button(root, text="red", command= red)
    c.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    return color

print(pick_color())
```

Comment: Yeah, I mean I could only get it to work when I did use a global variable. What I posted I guess is moreso the way I hoped it could work. Is there a way I can pass in non-local declarations into blue and red without making a global one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With what you have now, `red` and `blue` are creating their own, new variables called `color`; they aren't reassigning the `color` of `pick_color`. You need to tell Python that the inner `color` variables are `nonlocal`:

```
def pick_color():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    color = "blue"
    def blue():
        nonlocal color  # color is "nonlocal" to blue
        color = "blue"
        root.destroy()
    def red():
        nonlocal color  # And similarly, color is also nonlocal to red
        color = "red"
        root.destroy()
    b = tkinter.Button(root, text="blue", command = blue)
    b.pack()
    c = tkinter.Button(root, text="red", command= red)
    c.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    return color
```

Without `nonlocal`, Python doesn't know that you want to refer to the existing outer color, since Python doesn't have variable declarations.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect. Did not know that existed. I was wondering, based on your other comment about this being odd and Jared's suggestion, is it bad to do it this way? I just kind of liked the idea of this being contained in one function and one call since it's just some extraneous UI thing I was adding and this makes it feel  like it's adding less weight to my code.

Comment: @AskioFrio My comment about the odd setup was specifically regarding the use of Tkinter. It just strikes me as odd to launch a very short lived instance of Tkinter just to get such simple input from the user. It seems very heavy-handed. I'd just ask for such input using `input` or something similar. And I would take Jared's "not how it works" comment with a grain of salt since as my answer shows, Python has a keyword for just this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep this closed up in a function

That's not how python works, variables are local to the function they are defined in, if you want to make a variable assessable to multiple function you got 2 options, either make it global, or use a class.

```
import tkinter

class color():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = "blue"
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        
    def blue(self):
        self.color = "blue"
        self.root.destroy()
        
    def red(self):
        self.color = "red"
        self.root.destroy()

    def pick_color(self):
        b = tkinter.Button(self.root, text="blue", command = self.blue)
        b.pack()
        c = tkinter.Button(self.root, text="red", command = self.red)
        c.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()
        return self.color

choose = color()
print(choose.pick_color())
```

here I define the class colour and make the variable `self.color` local to the class, so it can be accessed by any of the classes methods such as `blue()` and `red()`.